# Azure tagging policy for Linux and Windows machines

Tags: azure, azure-policy

There is an ARM policy for checking particular tag existence on any VM in Azure:

```
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "AllOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "in": [
            "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines",
            "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines"
          ]
        },
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
          "exists": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "tagName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "tagName",
        "description": "Tag used to unequally identify a VM"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem:

How to create a separate policy, one for Linux, another for Windows VMs? I can not find a way how to filter. I.e. for Windows I use this policy script:

```
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
          "in": [
            "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
            "MicrosoftSQLServer"
          ]
        },
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
          "exists": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "tagName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "tagName",
        "description": "Tag used to help unequally identify a VM"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But above shows both Windows and Linux, as it's logic like "if VM is windows and has particular tag, means compliant; otherwise if there is no specific tag or VM is Linux, treats as non-compliant".

The need:

1x policy to see how many only Windows VMs are compliant (according the tag).

1x policy to see how many only Linux VMs are compliant (according the tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
"mode": "Indexed",
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
      },
      {
        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
        "in": [
          "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
          "MicrosoftSQLServer"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "auditIfNotExists",
    "details": {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[field('name')]",
      "existenceCondition": {
        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
        "exists": "true"
      }
    }
  }
},
"parameters": {
  "tagName": {
    "type": "String",
    "metadata": {
      "displayName": "tagName",
      "description": "Tag used to help unequally identify a VM"
    }
  }
}
```

Eventually came up to this working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/imagePublisher  instead of Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher